# Values are not setting into model class in angular7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building up an `ecommerce` web in which i have my `order`  `Model` `class` like this

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export class Order {
  constructor(){}
  amount: Number = 0;
  status: String = "";
  date: String = '';
  products: [any];
  userId: String = '';
  user : User;
}
```

And `user` model like this

```
export class User{
  name: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  country: string = '';
  city: string = '';
  mobileNumber: string = '';
  address: string = '';
  postalCode : string = '';
  nearBy : string = '';
  _id : string = '';
}
```

And i have a `cart.service.ts` in which i am calculating an `order` `total amount` like this

```
// Total amount
 public getTotalAmount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.cartItems.pipe(map((product: CartItem[]) => {
    return products.reduce((prev, curr: CartItem) => {
    return prev + curr.product.price * curr.quantity;
    }, 0);
 }));
}
```

Now on my `checkout.component.ts` i am binding values to `order` `Model` class like this

```
isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;
orderRawData: any;
order: Order;



placeOrder() {
this.cartService.getTotalAmount().subscribe(total=>{
  if (total) {
    console.log('amount : ',total);
    this.order.amount = total;
    this.orderRawData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));
    if (this.isUserLoggedIn) {
      this.order.userId = this.user._id;
    }else{
      this.order.user = this.user;
    }
    this.orderRawData.forEach((item,index)=>{
      this.order.products.push({
        id : item.product._id,
        quantity : item.quantity
      })
    })
    this.order.date = new Date().toLocaleString();
    this.order.status = 'Pending';
    console.log(this.order);
   }
 })

}
```

But it's giving me an error like this

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `order`:

```
order: Order;
```

Bu it never gets assigned an object, so is undefined when you try to updated one of its properties.

```
this.order.amount = total;
//        <--- undefined here
```

You somehow need to assign order, for example:

```
this.orderService.getOrder().subscribe(order => {
  this.order = order;
});
```

Before you can consider updating properties on it.

Comment: yes you are right. I updated my post. Please review updated post. Now error is coming at point where i am pushing an object into `order's` `product` array. How can i intialize order's product because there will be multiple objects inside `products` like [{id : '23423423', quantity : 23},{id : '23423423', quantity : 23},{id : '23423423', quantity : 23}]

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the order. Wherever that's happening, you also need to assign an empty array to products.

Answer (score 0):

Your order follows the 'Order' format but it's not initialize.

You can do like this:

1) `order: Order = {
       amount: 0,
       status: null,
       ....
   }`

or 2) Update the Order class like:

```
export class Order {
    amount: Number;
    status: String;
    ...

    constructor(_amount: Number = 0, _status: String = '', ...) {
        this.amount = _amount;  
        this.status = _status;
        ....
    }
}
```

In the component:

```
order: Order = new Order();
```